# option does not take a value error

Tags: python, django

I have this Command(BaseCommand) class with this defined:

```
make_option('--username', action='store_true', dest='username', default=None),
```

Then I try to run it like this:

```
python manage.py thescript --username=something
```

The output is:

```
manage.py: error: --username option does not take a value
```

Why?

---

**EDIT**

I am always getting None:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '--username=username ...'
    help = '...'

    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--username', action='store', default=None, help='...'),
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print options['username']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `store_true` will cause the command to store the boolean value `True` if the argument `--username` is given, rather then storing the next value.

I suspect that doing something along the lines of `action='store'` would do what you expect.

I think you're currently using optparse, correct? If so, you can find a full listing of the different kinds of actions available in the [optparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#defining-options).

Comment: Yes, optparse. action='store' is always returning the default value.

Comment: @AdamSilver -- Do you mean that after setting the action to `store` and calling `--username=something`, `username` is always set to `None` instead of `"something"`? If so, could you try editing your question to include an example of the code you currently have?

Comment: @AdamSilver -- Huh, I'm not really sure why your code isn't working. What happens if you change the default to some other value? You named the file with the command `thescript.py`, right? What happens if you try printing `args` and `options`?

Comment: print options: {'username': None, 'pythonpath': None, 'verbosity': '1', 'settings': None} print args: ('username=MY_PASSED_ARG_VAL',) ... why it's being stored in args not options? The docs says it will be stored in options: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: @AdamSilver -- Now I really have no idea. idk if this will help you debug further, but according to the django source code and optparse docs, it appears as if "leftover positional arguments after all options have been processed" are placed into `args`.  However, `--username=value` shouldn't fit that criteria, so I have no idea what the underlying issue might be. (For reference, django is doing `options, args = parser.parse_args(argv[2:])` where `parser` is an `OptionParser` instance.)